How do I wire a dishwasher switch correctly
My old switch in my dishwasher broke, I replaced it with another 4 pin switch but I can’t figure out what wires go on to each prong. One of the prongs as P written on it - I presumed it meant positive/live. But unsure. The colours I have are black, white, blue, and brown.


Was your first step to record how the wires were located on the old switch? If not then you need to work out input and output wires then which terminals do what on the switch. A multimeter will help with this.

It was a different switch but I didn’t record it nonetheless, silly mistake. The thing is I tried a colour orientation on each prong and it turns on. But it errors out after I start the dishwasher on a cycle. Would this be due to the improper wire setup on the switch or something else ?

please edit your question ... add make and model of dishwasher ... without that information,  the answer you provided is useless to anyone else

So I figured it out. It was Brown on P, then left to it was blue. On the bottom part of the picture, it goes white on the left and back on the right. Hope this helps someone!
